# How to replace `right floor' symbol with `hyphenation' symbol inside \Verb

Tags: hyphenation, fancyvrb

I'm now encountering a problem when using `\Verb` command from the package `fvextra`, which may be used as a drop-in replacement for package `fancyvrb`. `fvextra` will load `fancyvrb` if it has not yet been loaded, and then proceeds to patch `fancyvrb` and define additional features. The package `upquote` is loaded to give correct backticks (`` ` ``) and typewriter single quotation marks (`'`). When I attempt to use the command `\Verb` to produce a inline verbatim text the `\Verb`-enclosed text flows out of the line margins without line break.

According to documentation of `fvextra`, we should make use of `\Verb` with following options: `breaklines, breakafter=fun, breaksymbolright=-`, that's to say, we should input some LaTeX codes like the following: `\Verb[breaklines, breakafter=fun, breaksymbolright=-]|'integer, float, cons, symbol, string, vector, hash-table, subr, byte-code function, and record'|`. But another problem comes out of the situation above: the line breaking ends up with a `right floor` symbol rather than a `hyphenation` symbol which is exactly what I want to carry out.

My question is: how to replace the `right floor ⌋` symbol with the `hyphenation -` symbol?

BTW: I used `TeX Live-2022`, `xeLaTeX` engine, and compiled on `Sublime Text 4` with `macOS Sierra-Version 10.12.6`.

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[greek,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[svgnames,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage[headheight=15pt,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=3.81cm,right=3.54cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 
 \fancyhead[CO]{Tex Test}
 \fancyhead[CE]{Rédigé par Alex}
 \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\oldstylenums{\thepage}}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
  A Lisp \verb|'object'| is a piece of data used and manipulated by Lisp programs. For our purposes, a \verb|'type'| or \verb|'data type'| is a set of possible objects. Every \verb|'object'| belongs to at least one \verb|'type'|, but types can overlap, so objects can belong to two or more types. \\

Primitive types: A few fundamental object types are built into Emacs. These, from which all other types are constructed, are called \verb|'primitive'| types. Each object belongs to one and only one primitive type. These types include \Verb[breaklines, breakafter=fun, breaksymbolright=-]|'integer, float, cons, symbol, string, vector, hash-table, subr, byte-code function, and record'| plus several special types, such as \verb|'buffer'|, that are related to editing.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: if using xetex, never use either of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} ` also never end a paragraph with `...s. \\ ` (latex does warn about these)

Answer (score 0):

You want `breakaftersymbolpre`.

Note that `breakafter` takes as value the list of characters after which a break is permissible, not a string.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage[headheight=15pt,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=3.81cm,right=3.54cm]{geometry} 

\begin{document}

A Lisp \verb|'object'| is a piece of data used and manipulated by 
Lisp programs. For our purposes, a \verb|'type'| or \verb|'data type'| 
is a set of possible objects. Every \verb|'object'| belongs to at least 
one \verb|'type'|, but types can overlap, so objects can belong to 
two or more types.

Primitive types: A few fundamental object types are built into Emacs. 
These, from which all other types are constructed, are called 
\verb|'primitive'| types. Each object belongs to one and only one 
primitive type. These types include 
\Verb[
  breaklines,
  breakafter=fun,
  breakaftersymbolpre=-,
]|'integer, float, cons, symbol, string, vector, hash-table, subr, byte-code function, and record'| 
plus several special types, such as \verb|'buffer'|, that are related to editing.

\end{document}
```

I removed everything inessential for the problem, but note that `fontenc` should almost never be loaded with XeLaTeX and `inputenc` never at all.

Also, never use `\\` at end of paragraph. Ever.

[image]